# SetMargin in a manager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have a Grid view with some items displayed.How can i set the margin in grid view so that the items will be inside that margin and not within the scope of the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

if ur using `GridFieldManager` then see this :

```
grid.setColumnProperty(int coolumn,int property,int value);
```

where `grid` is the object of `GridFieldManager`;